# How to get highest value from ArrayList and display the info

Tags: java

I need to find the highest value (sales) from an ArrayList and show up what shop has the highest sales for each quarter.

```
        BufferedReader inputFile = null;
        PrintWriter outputFile = null;

        BookStore bs;
        ArrayList <BookStore> data = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            inputFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("bookstoresales.txt"));
            outputFile = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter ("bookstoreoutput.txt"));

            String indata = null;

            while ((indata = inputFile.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println (indata);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (indata, ",");

                String storeBranch = st.nextToken();
                String storeAddress = st.nextToken();
                double jan = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double feb = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double mac = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double apr = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double may = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double jun = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double jul = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double aug = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double sep = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double oct = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double nov = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());
                double dec = Double.parseDouble (st.nextToken());

                bs = new BookStore (storeBranch, storeAddress, jan, feb, mac, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec);

                data.add(bs);
            }

            outputFile.println ("\n\n=================================== The Highest Bookstore Sales Per Quarter  ===================================");


            for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
            {
                //This is where I got stucked.
            }

            outputFile.println ("\nQuarter 1 : The Highest sales is Bookstores : " + //getbranch name from the highest sales  + " with value of + //the highest value");


            inputFile.close();
            outputFile.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {
            System.out.println ("File not found!");
        }

        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println (ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to get and display the shop name along with the highest sales value. I'm quite confused when it comes to ArrayList.

Comment: If you were doing this manually, how would you do it?  You'd start at the top and look down the list, remembering the largest value you've seen so far.

Comment: consider using an array `double[] months = new double[12]` instead of having all those double variables

Comment: Start by figuring out how to loop through an ArrayList.

Comment: Try with resources is recommended instead of manually closing inputFile and outputFile. Also `bs` should probably be declared inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable called `max`. In the loop, if the item of the list is higher than `max`, set `max` to that item.

```
BookStore max = data.get(0);
for (BookStore bs : data) {
    if (bs.sales > max.sales)  {
        max = bs;
    }
}
```

Comment: `BookStore.sales` is not the total for each quarter. This will give the per-month max.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8:

```
BookStore max = 
    data.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(bs -> bs.getJan() + ... + bs.getDec()))
        .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way would be to use [Collections.max()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
Collections.max(data, new Comparator<BookStore>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(BookStore a, BookSore b) {
        return a.sales - b.sales;
    }
});
```

Or if `BookStore` is a `Comparable`, then simply:

```
Collections.max(data);
```